# Show that there exists $g: \mathbb{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic such that $g(z)^n = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{\Omega}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I'm learning about complex analysis and need some help with this problem:

> Let $\mathbb{\Omega}$ open, simply connected, $f: \mathbb{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic without zeros in $\Omega$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there exists $g: \mathbb{\Omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic such that $g(z)^n = f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{\Omega}$.

If I understand the problem correctly we want to show that there exists $g(z) = \sqrt[n]{f(z)}$ analytic in $\Omega$ but I have no idea how to tackle it.

Comment: There is a branch of $z\mapsto\sqrt[n]{z}$ defined on $f(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Batominovski: There may not be, say if $f(z) = \exp(z)$ and $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$.  $\Omega$ is simply connected, not necessarily $f(\Omega)$.

Comment: @orangeskid  Yep, you are absolutely right.  I was carelessly thinking that $f(\Omega)$ is simply connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the domain is simply connected, there is an analytic branch of $\log f(z)$ on $\Omega$ given by $L(z)$, where 
$$L(z) = \int_{z_0}^z {f'(z) \over f(z)}\,dz$$
Here $z_0$ is any fixed point in $\Omega$, and the integral is over any curve starting at $z_0$ and ending at $z$. Since the domain is simply connected, by Cauchy's theorem this definition of $L(z)$ does not depend on which curve is chosen. It is not hard to show that $e^{L(z)} = f(z)$ for all $z \in \Omega$. Therefore ${\displaystyle g(z) = e^{L(z) \over n}}$ will satisfy 
$$g(z)^n = e^{L(z)} = f(z)$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember we deal with branching through the exponential. 
$$ \sqrt[n] { f(z) } = \exp \left ( \frac{ \ln  f(z) } {n} \right) = \exp \left ( \frac{ \ln | f(z) | + i \arg f(z) } { n} \right ) = \exp \left ( \frac{ \ln | f(z) | }{n} \right ) \exp \left ( \frac{ i (\text{Arg } f(z) + 2\pi k) } {n} \right) $$
where $\ln | f(z) | $ is well defined since $|f(z)| >0$ on $\Omega$ and $k \in [0, n-1]$, thus we've found $n$ possible $g(z)$'s with the property $g(z)^n = f(z)$

Comment: This doesn't use that $\Omega$ is simply connected, which is necessary, since e.g. it's impossible to take a root of $f(z)=z$ on annulus around the origin.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is not simply connected then your $arg f(z)$ might have to be such that $g(z)$ is not analytic. You need to show that in the simply connected case the resulting $g(z)$ is analytic.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is also valid if instead of analytic functions we consider smooth, or continuous. The important thing: We have an $n$-fold  covering map 
$p \colon \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, 
$z \mapsto p(z) =  z^n$. Given now a continuous map $f$ from a simply connected open set $\Omega$ ( manifold, etc) to (the bottom) $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ ( the top one), $\omega_{0} \in \Omega$ and $y_0$ so that $p(y_0) = f(\omega_0)$, there exists a (unique) continuous map $g \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ so that $p\circ g = f$ and $g(\omega_0) = y_0$ ( the existence and uniqueness of liftings). Since the covering $p$ is locally an analytic isomorphism, $g$ will be analytic (smooth) whenever $f$ will be so.